# Django multiple models in CreateView

Tags: django, django-models

Hello I am trying to create a view with the following:

[image]

In the createview model, I am trying to render models (Report, LaborForce, Checklist, and ContractItem) to a form. The user will be able to search add LaborForce, Checklist, and ContractItem from a database I have already populated with and there will be a custom field for specifying amount. After submitting the form (validated for any errors), it will create instances combining the items with the specified amount into the report. I am having trouble passing these models to the view.

Or

Should I just make everything a foreignKey to Contract, have a separate function to render a report rather have a model of it, and store it as a .pdf entry in User. Use Contract as a parent form and the rest as inline forms.

I am trying to make the reports editable which is why I am splitting it up into different models and I have had issues of adding quantities to the models itself which is why I have instances of the model.

Comment: I'm not really following exactly what you want to do. You want to *reuse* the `Create` for all models? How would the form look like? One form *per* model? Or one form that "combines" all models? If so, then why not use a single model?

Comment: I want to use one form for all the models.

Comment: Corrections: All instances should have Int: Quantity